# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function initslider-1.js:1 (anonymous function) AmazingSlider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have gone through the other posts also. But I didn't get any solution finally I have my own question.
I am trying to add Jquery image slider into my project, I am using Codeigniter Platform as I am running this slider stand alone it is working fine. But not in CI it throws error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function initslider-1.js:1
(anonymous function)**. Anybody will suggest me any help.[image]

see following are the js files which I am including.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
```

[Click here to see the ref.](http://dtm.indelust.com/v2/index.php/womenswear)

Comment: Can you show how you are including JS references?

Comment: I suppose you included the slider library before `jQuery`... If thats the case, switch the references, so that `jQuery` is included first.

Comment: See I have added in my question, which lib I am using.

Answer (score 0):

try removing one of the jQuery `script`-tags.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="sliderengine/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
<script src="sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
```

Comment: also if you remove the other one?

Comment: Yes I have tried with both :-( even I replace the JQuery with $ still it is same

Comment: Have you also tried `$(...)` instead of `jQuery(..)` or adding `jQuery.noConflict();` in the first place? Im not sure if noconflict-syntax works w/O this..

Comment: alright, sorry, then i suggest checking if all script are actually loaded. sorry this didn't help..

Comment: http://dtm.indelust.com/v2/index.php/womenswear check this URL for a ref @nozzleman

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two jQuery at the same page. try this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>
<script src="sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think i have found the error
"src" is not correct
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>